# How to detect when UICollectionView complete loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I wonder is it possible to detect when `UICollectionView` after call `realodData` complete measuring `contentSize`.

It's I need to make `scrollToItemAtIndexpath` or more things that depends on `contentSize`?

I try solutions on Stack, but they not any time work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found pretty (i think) solution:

```
- (void)reloadDataCV {
 __weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;

 [wSelf.cv reloadData];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 NSLog(@"HeightGCD:%@", @(wSelf.cv.contentSize.height));
 [wSelf.cv scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:50 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
 });
```

Here i made example of how it's works

https://github.com/NelepovDmitry/iOSCommonMistakes/tree/master/iOS/CollectionView/TestCollectionGCD

Comment: I like how you got the sample working even before asking the question.

Comment: This does work! However I am not sure why though? Can you explain why it works?